# Will Perfino Alert show the exact place where the issue happened

Tags: perfino

Will alert in Perfino JVM Perfomance monitoring show the exact place where the issue happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a stack trace, then no. An alert is a high-level event and is associated with a time, a VM and has a description that tells you what happened.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Yes I was looking for the information like problematic method or class or stack trace etc.

Comment: For that purpose, use "VM Data Views->Method sampling", you can filter by transaction and policy violation type. In "VM Data Views->Transactions->Call Tree" there are also links to the method samples.